How to reset and prevent localStorage data from persisting in JavaScript on page reload?
I'm working on a JavaScript application where I manage a table of products. Each product row can be dynamically updated, and I store the updates in localStorage (both the original product list and any newly added products). However, I am encountering an issue where the addedProducts data persists in localStorage even after I explicitly reset it on page load.
Problem:
On page load, I am trying to reset the addedProducts array to an empty state. This is working as long as I stay on the same page.
However, if I navigate away and return to the page, the data from localStorage gets re-populated in the addedProducts array after the page completes loading, despite attempting to clear it.
I am unsure why the data persists and why it continues to populate even after I’ve explicitly
reset addedProducts.
What I've tried:
I tried resetting addedProducts to an empty array upon page load, but it still retrieves old data from localStorage once the page completes loading. (Again, as long as I remain on the same page there is no problem. If I naviaget away and return to the page, the data in addedProducts is pre populated.)
I also tried clearing localStorage during the beforeunload event, but the problem still occurs on page reload. Stuck.
My code:
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Fetch previously saved original products from localStorage (if any)
    let originalProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('originalProducts')) || [];
    let lastSavedRowIndex = originalProducts.length > 0 ? parseInt(originalProducts[originalProducts.length - 1].rowIndex) : -1;

    // Ensure addedProducts is always reset and never fetched from localStorage
    let addedProducts = [];  // Explicitly reset addedProducts to an empty array

    // Function to save original products to localStorage
    function saveOriginalProducts() {
        const productRows = document.querySelectorAll('#pos_table tbody tr');
        const products = [];

        productRows.forEach(row => {
            const rowIndex = row.getAttribute('data-row_index');

            // Extract product details
            const productNameElement = row.querySelector('.text-link');
            const productName = productNameElement ? productNameElement.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim() : '';
            const productQtyElement = row.querySelector('.input_quantity');
            const productQty = productQtyElement ? productQtyElement.value.trim() : '';
            const productPriceElement = row.querySelector('.pos_unit_price_inc_tax');
            const productPrice = productPriceElement ? productPriceElement.value.trim() : '';
            const productSubtotalElement = row.querySelector('.pos_line_total');
            const productSubtotal = productSubtotalElement ? productSubtotalElement.value.trim() : '';

            // Push only valid rows
            if (rowIndex && productName && productQty && productPrice && productSubtotal) {
                products.push({
                    rowIndex: rowIndex,
                    name: productName,
                    qty: productQty,
                    price: productPrice,
                    subtotal: productSubtotal
                });
            }
        });

        if (products.length > 0) {
            localStorage.setItem('originalProducts', JSON.stringify(products));
            console.log("Original products successfully saved to localStorage:", products);
        }
    }

    // Function to save added products to localStorage
    function saveAddedProducts() {
        const productRows = document.querySelectorAll('#pos_table tbody tr');
        const newAddedProducts = [];

        productRows.forEach(row => {
            const rowIndex = row.getAttribute('data-row_index');

            // Extract product details
            const productNameElement = row.querySelector('.text-link');
            const productName = productNameElement ? productNameElement.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim() : '';
            const productQtyElement = row.querySelector('.input_quantity');
            const productQty = productQtyElement ? productQtyElement.value.trim() : '';
            const productPriceElement = row.querySelector('.pos_unit_price_inc_tax');
            const productPrice = productPriceElement ? productPriceElement.value.trim() : '';
            const productSubtotalElement = row.querySelector('.pos_line_total');
            const productSubtotal = productSubtotalElement ? productSubtotalElement.value.trim() : '';

            // Check if the product is new (rowIndex is greater than lastSavedRowIndex)
            if (parseInt(rowIndex) > lastSavedRowIndex) {
                newAddedProducts.push({
                    rowIndex: rowIndex,
                    name: productName,
                    qty: productQty,
                    price: productPrice,
                    subtotal: productSubtotal
                });
            }
        });

        // Remove duplicates from addedProducts if they exist in originalProducts
        newAddedProducts.forEach(newProduct => {
            // Remove any existing product with the same rowIndex in addedProducts
            addedProducts = addedProducts.filter(existingProduct => existingProduct.rowIndex !== newProduct.rowIndex);

            // Now add the new product to addedProducts
            addedProducts.push(newProduct);
        });

        // Log the updated addedProducts BEFORE saving it to localStorage
        console.log("Updated addedProducts:", addedProducts);

        // Now save to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('addedProducts', JSON.stringify(addedProducts));

        // Update the last saved rowIndex
        lastSavedRowIndex = Math.max(...newAddedProducts.map(p => parseInt(p.rowIndex)), lastSavedRowIndex);
    }

    // Function to handle input changes (including quantity, price, and subtotal)
    function handleInputChange(event) {
        const row = event.target.closest('tr');
        const rowIndex = row.getAttribute('data-row_index');

        // Extract updated product details directly from the row
        const productNameElement = row.querySelector('.text-link');
        const productName = productNameElement ? productNameElement.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim() : '';
        const productQtyElement = row.querySelector('.input_quantity');
        let productQty = productQtyElement ? productQtyElement.value.trim() : '';
        productQty = productQty.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); // Sanitize quantity to only allow numbers

        const productPriceElement = row.querySelector('.pos_unit_price_inc_tax');
        const productPrice = productPriceElement ? productPriceElement.value.trim() : '';
        const productSubtotalElement = row.querySelector('.pos_line_total');
        const productSubtotal = productSubtotalElement ? productSubtotalElement.value.trim() : '';

        // Validate the productQty
        if (!productQty || isNaN(productQty) || parseFloat(productQty) <= 0) {
            productQty = '1'; // Default to 1 if the value is invalid
        }

        // Recalculate the subtotal (if applicable)
        const calculatedSubtotal = (parseFloat(productQty) * parseFloat(productPrice)).toFixed(2);
        if (productSubtotal !== calculatedSubtotal) {
            row.querySelector('.pos_line_total').value = calculatedSubtotal;
        }

        // Update the addedProduct array
        const updatedProduct = {
            rowIndex: rowIndex,
            name: productName,
            qty: productQty,
            price: productPrice,
            subtotal: calculatedSubtotal
        };

        // Check if the row belongs to originalProducts
        const originalIndex = originalProducts.findIndex(p => p.rowIndex === rowIndex);
        if (originalIndex !== -1) {
            // If the product exists in originalProducts, remove it from addedProducts
            const addedIndex = addedProducts.findIndex(p => p.rowIndex === rowIndex);
            if (addedIndex !== -1) {
                addedProducts.splice(addedIndex, 1); // Remove the product from addedProducts
            }
        } else {
            // Update existing product in addedProducts
            const addedIndex = addedProducts.findIndex(p => p.rowIndex === rowIndex);
            if (addedIndex !== -1) {
                addedProducts[addedIndex] = updatedProduct;
            } else {
                // Add as a new product if not found in either list
                addedProducts.push(updatedProduct);
            }
        }

        // Update localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('originalProducts', JSON.stringify(originalProducts));
        localStorage.setItem('addedProducts', JSON.stringify(addedProducts));
        console.log("Updated originalProducts:", originalProducts);
        console.log("Updated addedProducts:", addedProducts);
    }

    // Attach event listeners for product changes
    function addEventListenersToTable() {
        const productRows = document.querySelectorAll('#pos_table tbody tr');
        productRows.forEach(row => {
            const qtyInput = row.querySelector('.input_quantity');
            const priceInput = row.querySelector('.pos_unit_price_inc_tax');
            
            // Add event listeners to the input fields
            if (qtyInput) {
                qtyInput.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange);
            }

            if (priceInput) {
                priceInput.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange);
            }
        });
    }

    // Initialize table and event listeners
    const posTable = document.querySelector('#pos_table tbody');
    if (posTable) {
        saveOriginalProducts();
        addEventListenersToTable();
    } else {
        console.warn("POS table not found on the page.");
    }

    // Detect changes in the product table
    if (posTable) {
        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
            saveAddedProducts(); // Save newly added products
            addEventListenersToTable(); // Reattach listeners
        });

        observer.observe(posTable, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    }

    // Clear localStorage on page unload
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
        localStorage.removeItem("addedProducts");  // Clear added products on page exit
        console.log("Clearing addedProducts from localStorage before leaving the page.");
    });
});
</script>


Data persists because that's the whole point of local storage. If you don't want the stuff to last between page reloads, don't save it in local storage.

what's the alternative? I need to reset it on page refresh so that it cannot be retrieved when i return.

<head><script>localStorage.clear();</script>..... - done

The localStorage.clear(); only works if i refresh while I am on the same page. If however I navigate to a different page and then visit the same page again /pos/19896/edit the addedProduct array still contains data. Your suggestion works if I refresh without navigating away.

« what's the alternative? ». Variables? (Sorry if that sound dismissive or ironic or anything. I am probably missing something that would explain why you don't just store your data in a javascript variable. But you didn't really said anything to explain why would you want to use localStorage, whose whole purpose is to persist, when you don't want it to persist. Some, some more details are required, I would say)

I want to store the data client side temporarily and then send it to the browser print. The reason I wanted the data to be cleared is because if it retained and I need to save other data there would be some data conflicts and therefore lead to inconsistencies and inaccuracies.

Variables worked! Thank you!
